# How to prevent a UILabel from blocking a touch to a parent UIButton in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, uibutton, uilabel

I have a UIButton that has four child UILabels that contain information about the button's functionality. When I click the center of the button the action does not fire because it is being blocked by the UILabels but when I click the outside of the button the action does fire. Is there a way to prevent the UILabels from blocking the action firing?

Comment: have you tried disable user interaction for that label by setting `.isUserInteractionEnabled = false`?

Comment: How could you fire the action when click OUTSIDE of the button? You sure about this?

Comment: @YunCHEN There is a margin of 5 between the UILabels and the sides of the UIButton so when I click in the margin the action fires

Comment: @SmedleyDSlap, for me, the label does not influence the button, could you show us you code that adds label into the button?

Comment: @Tj3n You were correct I just forgot to set .isUserInteractionEnabled = false to the UIStackView that organized the UILabels

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You'll need to set `isUserInteractionEnabled = false` on any view that is above the button, or a subview of it.

By default `UILabel` have it set to `false`, but as you mentioned in the comments, `UIStackView` does not. So calling `isUserInteractionEnabled = false` on it will do the trick ┌( ಠ‿ಠ)┘

Comment: Ahh, for so long time I never tested touch handles above another I never tought that the touch would "go through" to the view below it. :) Upvoted , deleted my answer.